# Как распарсить строку, которая имеет дробные числа

Tags: java

Имеется к примеру вот такой текст
**Это стоит 11 бакс, 5.0 а 110 вот это 1.1 - 12.**
Нужно целые числа заменить словами.
Т.е. итог должен выглядеть таким образом
**Это стоит одиннадцать бакс, 5.0 а сто десять вот это 1.1 - двенадцать.**
Не понимаю какую регулярку применить, чтобы двенадцать тоже учитывало, т.к. там конец предложения и получается 12.

Comment: Разбивай на массив с разделителем пробел, далее проверяй каждый элемент на целочисленное число, меняй этот элемент на текст, и обратно собирай строку из элементов массива

Comment: Так на 12. он будет false.

Comment: Сделайте проверку на точку в конце предложения. До разбивки на массив

Comment: Да это не то...А если будет число перед запятой стоять? Тоже проверку дополнительную делать?

Comment: Я вам предложил алгоритм, а вы уж думайте. Я же не знаю откуда вы эти предложения берете

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение может выглядеть так:

```java
Pattern num = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\.)\\d+(?!\\.\\d+)");
```

- `(?<!\\.)` - look-behind: чтобы не было десятичной точки *перед* последовательностью цифр
- `\\d+` - последовательность из минимум одной цифры
- `(?!\\.\\d+)` - look-ahead: после цифр нет точки, за которой идёт последовательность цифр

---

Для замены чисел на слова начиная с Java 9 можно применить метод [`Matcher::replaceAll(Function<MatchResult, String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-), позволяющий преобразовать совпадение в регулярке в нужное значение, т.е. в данном случае число в слова.

Например, функция `translate` для преобразования чисел в диапазоне `[0, 999]` может быть такой:

```java
static final String[] below20 = {
    "ноль", "один", "два", "три", "четыре", "пять", "шесть", "семь", "восемь", "девять",
    "десять", "одиннадцать", "двенадцать", "тринадцать", "четырнадцать", 
    "пятнадцать", "шестнадцать", "семнадцать", "восемнадцать", "девятнадцать"
};
static final String[] tens = {
    "двадцать", "тридцать", "сорок", "пятьдесят", "шестьдесят", "семьдесят", "восемьдесят", "девяносто"
};
static final String[] hunds = {
    "сто", "двести", "триста", "четыреста", "пятьсот", "шестьсот", "семьсот", "восемьсот", "девятьсот"
};

static String translate(int i) {
    if (i == 0) return below20[0];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (i >= 100) {
        sb.append(hunds[i / 100 - 1]);
    }
    int p = i % 100;
    if (sb.length() > 0 && p > 0) {
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    if (p < 20) {
        sb.append(below20[p]);
    } else {
        sb.append(tens[p/10 - 2]).append(' ').append(below20[p % 10]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Для упрощения вызова `translate` как ссылки на метод, можно написать адаптер:

```java
static String translate(MatchResult mr) {
    return translate(Integer.parseInt(mr.group()));
}
```

Тест:

```java
String s = "Это стоит 11 бакс, 5.0 а 110 вот это 1.1 - 12.";

Pattern num = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\.)\\d+(?!\\.\\d+)");
// теcтовый вывод совпадений регулярки
num.matcher(s).results() // Stream<MatchResult>
    .map(MatchResult::group) // Stream<String>
    .forEach(System.out::println);

String words = num.matcher(s).replaceAll(MyClass::translate);

System.out.println(words);
```

Результат:

```
11
110
12
Это стоит одиннадцать бакс, 5.0 а сто десять вот это 1.1 - двенадцать.
```

Comment: Не совсем то, что мне нужно конечно, но полезно! Смотри, а если парсю строку на слова по пробелу и хочу каждое слово проверять является ли оно числом. Т.е. if (arrayWord[i].matches("\\b\\d+\\b"), то тогда я его уже беру и делаю с ним замену. Вот по сути данная регулярка должна же отрабатывать на всех числах, будь они с точкой в конце или с запятой, но что-то не работает

Comment: Использование границы слов `\b` (то есть пустого места между `\w` и `\W`) в данном случае вполне бессмысленно; `matches("\\b\\d+\\b")` не "отловит" числа, оканчивающиеся точкой, запятой и прочими непробельными символами, так как `matches` только проверяет соответствие строки _целиком_.  Можно допилить регулярку, чтобы допускалась точка в конце `\d+\.?`, но тогда её придётся убирать вручную из строки при преобразовании в целое число.

Comment: Касаемо _Не совсем то, что мне нужно конечно_ -- данное решение показывает, что разбиение строки на слова по пробелам с последующей пересборкой строки совершенно не обязательно, если можно корректно определить целые числа и эффективно их заменить.